# How to Pass @Value to a @Component for Spring Unit Testing

Tags: spring, eclipse, testing

Im writing unit tests for services, controllers, etc however theres is a @Component that has the following values

```
@Component
Public class myclass
   @Autowired
   Private MyTemplate myTemplate

   @Value("$someString")
   Private String someString

   @PostConstruct
   Public void loadString()
      ...
```

How would I manually load values into the @Values? I have tried with Mocks, TestPropertySource, ReflectionTestUtils, among other ways found around

Comment: Turn `someString` into a constructor parameter, move `@Value` annotation to the constructor argument, and then set it accordingly when initializing your class in the unit test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can inject the @Value in test class by ReflectionTestUtils. Load container only in case of Controllers. For writing test cases for services and dao you don't need to load the spring container.

```
public class TestClass{
 private @InjectsMock ServiceClass service; 

 @BeforeAll
 public void setUp(){
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(service, "someString", "someValue");
 }

//your test cases over here.
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks appreciate it!! Tried multiple things including Mockito, but this time helped.

Comment: Great! Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

I can immediately think of two options

1) You could define $someString in your test/resources/test.properties

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:test.properties")
public class ClassTest {

  }
```

2) do it manually

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class ClassTest {

    @Autowired
     private MyClass miclass;

 @Before
 public void setupObject() {
     miclass.setProperty("someting");
  }

  }
```

Comment: For some reason RunWith doesnt work, has trouble w Log4j of sorts.. appreciate it though!